# How can i procedurally change ring sizes in wave texture?

Tags: node-editor, procedural

I got to the point where I got each ring size different by having the *Wave Texture* go through a *Noise Texture*.

[image]

How can I get each ring to not be uniform like this drawing. Not exactly like the drawing since each ring isn't exactly circular but each ring having a constantly changing width.

[image]

I wrongly assumed by changing the ring width it would have the effect of the sides running down like this drawing. I'm not sure how to go about this. Any changes to the z scale in the *Mapping* node removes the side lines and the top/down center circles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you played with the Distortion  setting in the node ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this?

[image]

Or are you trying to get straighter sides?

If you want straighter sides just scale the Mapping Node in Z (scale it down).  0.1 in Z will give really straight sides:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can mix some noise into the texture coordinate space.

[image]

This has the unfortunate side effect of offsetting the center of the circle, so you would have to use the *Mapping* node to translate it back.

Comment: oof guess i didnt actually think this through because the reason i wanted the ring width different was so the sides would also differ in width... gonna follow your setup and see if i can figure out how to get it also vertically

Comment: I specifically left out the z axis, I can come back to it later.

Comment: i edited the post to clarify but would the solution be to have the ring texture on the top/bot faces and give the side faces a separate line texture that i can add noise to to get the effect? the rings and lines wouldnt match at the intersections but not sure how it could be done with the current ring texture